# Unhandled Exception when downloading Microsoft SQL server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have been doing my webapp project in my school lab and have since decided to bring it home and do. I have been using VS2012 and Microsoft SQL server 2008. I attempted to download microsoft SQL server in my computer and recevied this error i have never ever seen before.

[image]

I have typed dir C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework into the command prompt and here are the results

[image]

Does anyone knows how to solve and verify this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have .NET framework 4.0 installed?

Comment: `dir C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` at a command prompt will list  installed frameworks (or rather, their directories)

Comment: I have edited my post and added the result given by command prompt

Comment: Hm, can't see anything beyond normal there. The error message hints about not being able to load `System.dll` for 4.0, but debugging that further is not exactly straight forward. I think I'll have to leave it for someone that can actually try the installer, I'm on a Mac right now :)